# How to send data from viewController to NSObject Class hierarchy and vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegation

I am having a wrapper class from `WebViewJavascriptBridge` which get the data from JavaScript to Objective C where I need to send this data to its extended or other class for appropriate class, also from down to up I need the same thing like any thing change from `viewController` change orientation then my `OrientationHandler` Class notified, then `EventManager` then, `CommunicationManager` and that notify to that bridge class.

This is bridge class code to initiate

```
[self.bridge registerHandler:@"callHandler" handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback){
            [[CommunicationManager sharedInstance] initWithActionRequest:data];
            responseCallback(@200);
        }];
```

Here my CommunicationManager choose what class need to load..

```
-(BOOL)initWithActionRequest:(id)request {
    if ([request isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary* requestType = (NSDictionary*)request;
        NSAssert((requestType != nil), @"request dictionary is nill");

        NSArray* params = [requestType[@"eventType"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSAssert(([params count] == 3), @"params array is nill");

        if ([params[0] isEqualToString:@"DeviceManager"]) {
            DeviceManager* deviceManager = [[DeviceManager alloc] initWithDeviceManagerRequestType:requestType];
            deviceManager.serviceName = params[1];
            deviceManager.serviceAction = params[2];
            [deviceManager performActionBasedOnRequest];
            return YES;

        } else if ([params[0] isEqualToString:@"EventManager"]) {
            EventManager* eventManager = [[EventManager alloc] initWithEventManagerRequestType:requestType];
            eventManager.serviceName = params[1];
            eventManager.serviceAction = params[2];
            [eventManager performEventBasedOnRequest];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

then my DeviceManager Class execute which service need to start

```
-(BOOL)performActionBasedOnRequest {
    if ([_serviceName isEqualToString:@"SipHandler"]) {

        SipHandler* sipHandler = [[SipHandler alloc] init];
        [sipHandler startPJSIPWithOptions:nil];
        return YES;

    } else {

    }
    return NO;
}
```

then in the end my service class SipHandler load and run the method

```
-(BOOL)startPJSIPWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
    startPjsip(CLIENT_NAME, SERVER_HOST);
    return YES;
}
```

I have confusion how to flow the data in efficient way?

Comment: Maybe if you show a code example the question would be clearer.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have updated the code flow as I am trying to do.

Comment: I'd prefer use a singleton in this case. Anyway you need create a model as you can read here  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html.